# Why are the values of all the streampos -1 after seekg() from a vector of streampos?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream iFile;
std::string string;
std::vector<std::streampos> titlePos;

int main()
{
    iFile.open("presets.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    if (!iFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "iFile presets isnt open" << std::endl;
    }
    while (!iFile.eof())
    {
        iFile >> string;
        if (string == "%title")
        {
            iFile >> string;
            titlePos.emplace_back(iFile.tellg());
        }
    }
    for (int x = titlePos.size() - 1; x != -1; --x)
    {
        iFile.seekg(titlePos[x]);
        std::cout << titlePos[x] << std::endl;
        std::cout << iFile.tellg() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the `cout` for `listPos[x]` are all usual (I think), but once I transfer the `streampos` values to the `ifstream iFile`, they all result in a -1 being outputted (an error, I assume).

I do not understand why transferring the values causes an error, or how I would go about finding the cause of the error.

IN "presets.txt"

```
%title loc1

%title loc2

%title loc3
```

OUTPUT

```
-1
-1
26
-1
11
-1
```

Comment: Where to the values in `listPos` come from? What are `strings` and `word`? Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the listPos values come from a series of listPos.push_back(iFile.tellg) calls. I will try to make a MRE but im new to this site so it might take a bit.

Comment: EOF isn't set until an attempt is made to read past the end. The failed `iFile >> string` will also set the stream to a fail state (`fail()` will return true). Once failed, the seeks (and tells) won't work. You need to clear the error state after your EOF loop and before your output loop (with `ifile.clear()`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i tried that now and it is set back to fail after iFile.seekg(titlePos[x]), but not before

Comment: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/12149471)

Answer (score 0):

After a failure (excluding `eof`) reading data from a stream `tellg` and `seekg` will both also fail and return `-1`.

`while (!iFile.eof())` also means you check the stream state before reading values rather than after reading them. You should check whether each operation succeeds before using the value, this is the cause of the last entry in `titlePos` being `-1`.

To reset the stream to `good` you need to call `clear()`.

This should then work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream iFile;
std::string string;
std::vector<std::streampos> titlePos;

int main()
{
    iFile.open("presets.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    if (!iFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "iFile presets isnt open" << std::endl;
    }
    while (iFile)
    {
        if (!(iFile >> string))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (string == "%title")
        {
            if (!(iFile >> string))
            {
                std::cout << "error reading string\n";
                break;
            }
            titlePos.emplace_back(iFile.tellg());
        }
    }
    iFile.clear();
    for (int x = titlePos.size() - 1; x != -1; --x)
    {
        iFile.seekg(titlePos[x]);
        std::cout << titlePos[x] << std::endl;
        std::cout << iFile.tellg() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried clearing the iFile before setting its locations, but it still resulted in an error being returned.

Comment: Instead of `titlePos.clear();`, did you intend to write `iFile.clear();`?

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing `titlePos` and `iFile`. The line `titlePos.seekg(titlePos[x]);` does not make sense, as `titlePos`, which is a `std::vector`, does not have a member `seekg`. I believe it was correct before you changed it in your most recent edit.